# Warning of the permission in Aegir

Tags: users, features, aegir

I'm trying to add a site with Aigir and i'm getting this warning:

### Warning in features rebuild of permessi. No module defines permission "create article content".

### Warning in features rebuild of permessi. No module defines permission "create slides content".

### Warning in features rebuild of permessi. No module defines permission "delete any article content".

### Warning in features rebuild of permessi. No module defines permission "delete any slides content".

### Warning in features rebuild of permessi. No module defines permission "delete own article content".

### Warning in features rebuild of permessi. No module defines permission "delete own slides content".

### Warning in features rebuild of permessi. No module defines permission "delete terms in tags".

### Warning in features rebuild of permessi. No module defines permission "edit any article content".

### Warning in features rebuild of permessi. No module defines permission "edit any slides content".

### Warning in features rebuild of permessi. No module defines permission "edit own article content".

### Warning in features rebuild of permessi. No module defines permission "edit own slides content".

### Warning in features rebuild of permessi. No module defines permission "edit terms in tags".

all permissions are exported with features & features_roles_permissions.
the problem is on the new created site this permissions are not set for any of the roles set in the module.
any idea?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that the permissions are created before there are defined (since you need to have the content types created before the permissions are created).

This could be fixed with proper dependencies (since the feature with the permissions depends on the feature(s) with the content types.

Comment: I'have the creation content type code in profile.install, if this is the problem i'll sperate the code in a module and place it just before the permission module.i'll let you know

Comment: @Ossama If your install profile depends on the module with the permissions, that module will be installed before the install profile and give the errors you wrote

Comment: you are right, now i separated the code and it works very fine, thank you very much. i can't vote your answer because i'm under 15 reputatione

Comment: @Ossama You can always mark with the green check to let other know that this fixed your issue if others experience the same issue